# Same property for same objects appears twice

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I have an object ($node). I need to update the value of a property of the object, I first unset it and then update it

```
  unset($node->field_the_tranasction_status‎[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]);
  $node->field_the_tranasction_status‎[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid']=97;
```

However, If I print the $node object afterwards using print_r($node), the property field_the_tranasction_status‎ appears twice as follows and it is causing problems for me when calling the save() function:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [vid] => 1794
    [uid] => 1
    [title] => 2222 - 1
    [status] => 0
    [comment] => 0
    [promote] => 0
    [sticky] => 0
    [nid] => 1471
    [type] => donations
    [language] => en
    [created] => 1495892029
    [changed] => 1495892068
    [tnid] => 0
    [translate] => 0
    [revision_timestamp] => 1495892029
    [revision_uid] => 1
    [field_authorization_code] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_amount] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_currency_iso] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 840
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_postal_address] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [country] => PS
                            [administrative_area] => 
                            [sub_administrative_area] => 
                            [locality] => 2222
                            [dependent_locality] => 
                            [postal_code] => 
                            [thoroughfare] => 222
                            [premise] => 
                            [sub_premise] => 
                            [organisation_name] => 
                            [name_line] => 
                            [first_name] => 
                            [last_name] => 
                            [data] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_donor_name] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 2222
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => 2222
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_credit_card_number] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => XXXXXXXXXXXX1111
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_reference_number] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => null
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_signature] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => null
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_response_code] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_reason_code] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 513
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_signature_verified] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_reason_description] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 3D Secure Message does not exist
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_serial] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 135
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_email] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 21312312@ksdasd.com
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => 21312312@ksdasd.com
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_phone] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 2222
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => 2222
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_anonymous] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_campaign] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_perk] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_donation_program] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tid] => 96
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_processed] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => No
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_referral_url] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => https://www.taawon.org/donate
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => https://www.taawon.org/donate
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_transaction_status] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_the_tranasction_status] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tid] => 101
                        )

                )

        )

    [name] => admin
    [picture] => 0
    [data] => b:0;
    [field_the_tranasction_status‎] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tid] => 98
                        )

                )

        )

    [timestamp] => 1495892068
    [publish_on] => 0
    [unpublish_on] => 0
    [xmlsitemap] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1471
            [type] => node
            [subtype] => donations
            [loc] => node/1471
            [language] => en
            [access] => 
            [status] => 0
            [status_override] => 0
            [lastmod] => 1495892068
            [priority] => 0.5
            [priority_override] => 0
            [changefreq] => 0
            [changecount] => 0
            [status_default] => 0
            [priority_default] => 0.5
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you show us your code about saving ? otherwise try to use `$node->field_the_tranasction_status‎[LANGUAGE_NONE] = array();` instead `unset` function